# Transparent background results in desaturated colors

Tags: cycles-render-engine, transparency

I have a scene with transparent objects (a resin drop on a microscope slide and beaker) lit by an HDRI environment. I'd like to render this with a transparent background, but this results in a desaturated greyed image. How can this be fixed? [image]